# Copy information from one spreadsheet to another based on a single factor

Tags: vba, excel, copy

```
   A   B     C
1. c   First Last 
2. d   First Last
3. e   First Last
4. c   First Last
5. c   First Last
```

I'm trying copy the information from columns B & C over to another worksheet (tab in the same document) based on the letter in column A. I only want first and last names to be transferred if the letter in Column A is a "c". Is there a formula or macro I can use to do this?

Comment: FYI, the first part of the post was meant to look like an excel sheet with three columns.  I want the letter in the first column to determine if the information from the second and third transfer to the next worksheet.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need this fully automated? If no then I'd suggest first sorting your data on first column and then just selecting/copying a range.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I do actually need it automated so that as we add new people, it automatically populates them on the next workbook.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a VBA expert. I'd try to propose a solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest answer is to create a pivot table based on on the data on your first worksheet. You can format the pivot table so that it looks similar to your original spreadsheet and then filter your column A to select only the letter "C".

One thing to be careful of, is that when you select your data range for the pivot table, be sure to select the entire columns. that way you can add more names and the pivot table will pick it up.

A couple of notes of concern in the pivot table options:

- turn off the totals and subtotals to make the pivot table look more
  like your original spreadsheet
- set it to update automatically, so that you don't have to be constantly refreshing

Hope this helps!